# variable value is not getting fetched in a stage in jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following script for jenkins pipeline where am trying to fetch the git successful commit,
Can someone please help me why the variable value is not printing?

```
 node(params.node)
   {

         try{          stage('fetchCommandOutput'){
                            dir('test'){

                                 powershell"""               
                                 def succesfulCommit=getCommandOutput("git rev-parse HEAD") //this is not working

                                 echo "git successful commit is " $succesfulCommit

                                 exit 0
                                 """
                                 }                         
                   }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
               echo e.toString()
     }

   }


   def getCommandOutput(cmd) {
       if (isUnix()){
          return sh(returnStdout:true , script: '#!/bin/sh -e\n' + cmd).trim()
       } else{
           stdout = bat(returnStdout:true , script: cmd).trim()
           result = stdout.readLines().drop(1).join(" ") 
           echo "result is ${result}"   \\\\this works fine
           return result
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `getCommandOutput(cmd)` as a Groovy function in your Pipeline. Therefore, invoking it from within a `powershell` step simply won’t work. Move the expression `def succesfulCommit=getCommandOutput("git rev-parse HEAD")` and subsequent line of code outside the `powershell` step.

Comment: thanks Aditya, is there a way I can get the git commit from inside a powershell?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your use case fully. You can replace `bat` with `powershell` in your function or run `git rev-parse HEAD` directly without invoking the function. See https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/.